# 2 questions about the client-side and server-side scripting languages?

Tags: client-side-scripting, server-side-scripting

this is questions about the client-side and server-side scripting languages

and i need know what the difference between them?

> 1 – What are the client-side scripting languages?

```
A.  HTML5
B.  CSS3
C.  jQuery
D.  ASP
E.  Ajax
F.  PHP

i think the answer q,b,c,e
```

> 2 - What are the server-side scripting languages?

```
A.   JavaScrist
B.  jQuery
C.  Ajax
D.  PHP
E.  XHTML
F.  XML

i think the answer d
```

is my answers correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Client-side scripting languages are executed on the client's side in the browser. So for the first question it would be A, B, C, E. I'm not sure about A or B though, because technically HTML and CSS aren't scripting languages, they're markup languages. HTML and CSS are used to render the page, jQuery is a JavaScript library. JavaScript is used to make pages interactive, and Ajax is used on the client side to request pages in the background.

If we want to be really technical, none of the answers for #1 are correct, as jQuery is a library written in JavaScript (which is a language) and Ajax is a JavaScript construct.

Server-side scripting languages are executed on the server's side. Your answer for the second question is correct. PHP is used on the server to create dynamic pages.

Comment: jQuery and AJAX are  not languages, and HTML and CSS are not scripting.

Comment: This question is worded fairly poorly, although I think the intention is fairly clear.